# How are locales persisted globally when setting it from a dropdown?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to persist a locale change based on the user setting the language from a bootstrap dropdown in a global `navbar` partial. It will change the language for the current page, but I don't know how to enable the locale for all subsequent routes.  The app works correctly when I manually insert the 2-char locale code (e.g., `ru`) into the URL (i.e., `localhost:3000/en/about`), so I know that the localizations are working correctly.  I'm not sure how to code a controller method so all routes/pages will use the locale.  Would greatly appreciate any guidance!

Snippet from my view:

```
<li class="dropdown">
  <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"><%= t(".dropdown.language") %> <span class="caret"></span></a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><%= link_to t(".dropdown.english"), :locale=>:en %></li>
    <li><%= link_to t(".dropdown.thai"), :locale=>:th %></li>
    <li><%= link_to t(".dropdown.russian"), :locale=>:ru %></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Code snippet from my `I18n.rb` initializer:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true
I18n.available_locales = [:en, :th, :ru]
```

Code snippets from my `routes.rb`:

```
  scope(
    '/(:locale)',
    locale: /#{I18n.available_locales.join('|')}/,
    defaults: { locale: I18n.default_locale }
  ) do
    get '/about' => 'pages#about'
    end
```

and finally, here is the relevant route after rake:

```
about GET (/:locale)/about(.:format) pages#about {:locale=>/en|th|ru/}
```

I had originally followed the guide to apply locale changes from within the `application_controller.rb` file as follows:

```
before_action :set_locale

def set_locale
  I18n.locale = params[:locale] || I18n.default_locale
end

def default_url_options
  { locale: I18n.locale }
end
```

but this just causes the app to render a completely blank page (no log errors or warning at all, just an `HTTP_RESPONSE: 200` with no content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to save the current value of `I18n.locale` to a session variable, and then fetch it back on each request. For example:

```
def set_locale
  # Note the ordering of params and session here, so that explicit params will still always override a saved setting
  I18n.locale = params[:locale] || session[:locale] || I18n.default_locale
  session[:locale] = I18n.locale
end
```

Comment: Thanks, @gwcodes. I will have a look. In the mean time, what would the code in the view look like? ( instead of: `<%= link_to t(".dropdown.russian"), :locale=>:ru %>` )

Comment: @Jasper33: your views shouldn't need to change. E.g. hitting path?locale=ru will still work, and then set the remembered default to `ru`. If you want to indicate the currently active language (and you have an `active` visual state defined), then you can use `link_to t(".dropdown.russian", locale: :ru, class: "#{'active' if I18n.locale == 'ru'}"`

Comment: Much appreciate @gwcodes.  Very useful link! So, in the final analysis, everything *should* be working, but I'm still baffled by the blank page being rendered.  It appears that any update to my `application_controller.rb` causes this behavior.  I will need to search down a different path to address that issue.  Cheers!